# OCaml type (int option list) list

Tags: list, types, ocaml

I'm trying to make a type (int option list) list variable.

let blah :(int option list) list   = [Some 30 
  ; Some 77] :: [Some 2 ; Some 3] ;;

However, this does not type check.
I guess I'm just really lost on the syntax.

Answer (score 6):

You almost got it:

```
let blah : (int option list) list = [Some 30 ; Some 77]::[[Some 2] ; [Some 3]]
```

Or, more readably:

```
let blah = [[Some 30; Some 77]; [Some 2]; [Some 3]]
```

The type problem is in the application of `::`: you have different types for the left hand side and the elements of the right hand side.

Comment: or rather `[Some 30 ; Some 77] :: [Some 2 ; Some 3] :: []`